# Modifying an input string using sed

Tags: sed

Using sed, how can I change an input string like `9872` to `39 38 37 32`  i.e. insert digit 3 before and a space after each digit of entered string `9872.`

Input string:

```
9872
```

Required output:

```
39 38 37 32
```

Comment: This is fairly trivial, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You have good answers. If "3" is not fixed, you can write: `n=3; sed "s/[0-9]/$n& /g" <<< "12345"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And just for completeness, a more general way using regex references.

```
echo 9872 | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]])/3\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 9872 | sed 's/./3&\ /g'
```

Comment: To be safe I would use `echo 9872 | sed 's/[0-9]/3& /g'` else it could to it with spurious whitespace and EOLs.

Comment: Also, I don't think the space needs to be escaped. Probably doesn't hurt anything, though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "9872" | sed 's/[0-9]/3& /g' 
39 38 37 32
```